# trying to create channel inside category discord.js v13

Tags: discord, discord.js

i'm trying to create a channel inside category
this is my code :

```js
let cate = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(
      (c) => c.name === "restricted" && c.type === "category")
if (!cate) return interaction.followUp('category not found')

let channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create("restricted", {
  type: "text",
  parent: cate.id,
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: interaction.guild.id,
      deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
    },
  ],
})
```

i tried so many ways but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

just use .setParent after creating the channel
**try:**

```js
await interaction.deferReply()
let cate = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(
      (c) => c.name === "restricted"&&c.type ==="catogory")
if (!cate) return interaction.editReply('category not found')
// remember don't put await here
let channel = interaction.guild.channels.create("restricted", {
  type: "text",
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: interaction.guild.id,
      deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
    },
  ],
}).then(channell=> channell.setParent(cate))
```

Comment: Can you, explain your code :' Just fixing the OP's code isn't really helping understand what exactly the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

In discord.js v13. Channel types are no longer named "category" or "text" or "voice". Instead their types are `GUILD_CATEGORY`, `GUILD_TEXT` etc..

Change this part of your code :

```js
      (c) => c.name === "restricted" && c.type === "category")
```

to

```js
      (c) => c.name === "restricted" && c.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY")
```

(category channels usually show up all uppercase so if you want to avoid problems try also lowercasing the name,
In the end, this line will look like this :

```js
      (c) => c.name.toLowerCase() === "restricted" && c.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY")
```

> [`Discord Developer Portal - Channel types`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channel-object-channel-types)